# Responding to Facebook Requests in iphone app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I’m using this to send a request to a friend on Facebook.  I’d like for the person that received the request to be able to open it and receive a bonus for accepting the request.  How would I go about acknowledging the request on the receiving end?

```
-(IBAction)sendRequest:(id)sender
{
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Come check out my app.",  @"message",
                               nil]; 

AppDelegate *aDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
[aDelegate.facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:self]  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [Android and iOS: Discovery via Requests Best Practices](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/26/android-and-ios--discovery-via-requests-best-practices/) official blog post.

It discusses (among other things) how to send user requests along with some relevant data, and then how to identify the request and get the associated data.